# What is the purpose of the inet_addr_lst kernel symbol in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to understand what is the purpose of the kernel symbol **inet_addr_lst**  as defined in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/devinet.c#L108 Does it contain a list of all the ip addresses on the system or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hashtable is an array of struct hlist_head pointers, where each one points to a different list, and each one of those lists holds all elements that are hashed to the same bucket. So every element is essentially part of a hlist and the hashtable only holds the head of these lists.

inet_addr_lst is a array of struct hlist_head type. so you can use this strcut to store and checking the ip address/ broadcast address . Example "you register all local registered broadcast addresses in inet_addr_lst"